# Error in unit testing with Jest after updating to npm 3.3.12

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, jestjs

I recently updated my project to node 5.1.0, npm 3.3.12 and updated all my dependencies... Now I'm fighting against a bunch of errors!

Initially I had the same error thats on this issue: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/554, that got easily fixed.

Bur now I'm getting this one now:

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined,
>   boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a
>   ReactClass (for composite components).

and

> Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

I have this in my package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "testRunner": "./node_modules/jest-cli/src/testRunners/jasmine/jasmine2",
    "scriptPreprocessor": "./node_modules/babel-jest",
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
        "./node_modules/es6-promise",
        "./node_modules/events",
        "./node_modules/fbjs",
        "./node_modules/flux",
        "./node_modules/history",
        "./node_modules/immutable",
        "./node_modules/lodash",
        "./node_modules/moment",
        "./node_modules/react",
        "./node_modules/react-addons-pure-render-mixin",
        "./node_modules/react-addons-test-utils",
        "./node_modules/react-d3",
        "./node_modules/react-dom",
        "./node_modules/react-modal",
        "./node_modules/react-router",
        "./node_modules/whatwg-fetch"
    ]
  }
```

And the relevant parts of my tests are:

```
var ImageGallery = require('../../../app/components/image-gallery/image-gallery');
imageGalleryComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <ImageGallery
        items={items}
        onSlide={onSlideMock}
        lazyLoad={false}
        showBullets={true}
        showThumbnails={true}
        showNav={true}
        slideInterval={4000}/>
);
```

Anyone ran into this issue? Any clues on how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my code I was using babel with "imports", so the problem was that in the tests I needed to use "imports" as well or just add a ".default" in the end of the require statement, something like this:

```
var ImageGallery = require('../../../app/components/image-gallery/image-gallery').default;
```